# Themes reset after deploying vaadin maven project

Tags: maven, themes, vaadin

We have vaadin maven project and every time after deploying themes are not working.
There are:
1) styles.scss file with

```
    @import "mytheme.scss";
    @import "addons.scss";
    .mytheme {
         @include addons;
         @include mytheme;
    }
```

2) mytheme.scss file with custom styles and:

```
    @import "../valo/valo.scss";
    @mixin mytheme {
    @include valo;...
```

3) UI class with

```
    @Theme("mytheme")
```

When I start project from eclipse - everything is working good, but after deploying application is working without themes.
Even after commenting

```
    <goal>compile-theme</goal>
```

nothing were changed.

Can anybody help me to make themes work correct?

Comment: Did you check the resulting war file to see if those resources are included?

Comment: In war file mytheme.scss file is without my changes

Answer (score 0):

I've removed this line from pom.xml and everything is working good

```
     <goal>compile-theme</goal>
```